# Power BI DAX Filter Matrix/Table Based on Slicer Selection

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've a parent / child slicer and would like to apply an extra filter when a child value is selected. Is the below scenario possible?

Thanks a lot!

**Table**

```
|Category|Sub-Cat  |Team|Filter Column|
|--------|---------|----|-------------|
|Cat1    |Dedicated|A   |Include      |
|Cat2    |Generic  |B   |Exclude      |
|Cat3    |Dedicated|C   |Include      |
```

**Slicer**
Category
-> Sub-Cat

**Expected Results:**
When a parent is selected, I want to show all Sub-Cats including Generic.  When a Child is selected, I only want the Dedicated shown.

**Matrix / Table - When Parent is selected (show everything)**

```
|Team|Filter Column|
|----|-------------|
|A   |Include      |
|B   |Exclude      |
|C   |Include      |
```

**Matrix / Table - When Child is selected (filter out exclude)**

```
|Team|Filter Column|
|----|-------------|
|A   |Include      |
|C   |Include      |
```

Comment: Why do you need slicer on category that case? if you wants everything when a category is selected, then just use slicer for sub_category. when nothing selected in sub_category slicer, this will show everything, but when something selected, it will only show rows for that particular sub_category only.

Comment: ok, consider this scenario.  There are 10 teams under marketing promoting products.  8 teams are dedicated to a particular product and 2 teams can work on any product.  So when I choose "Marketing - Parent slicer" I want to show all 10 teams, but when a particular product under Marketing is selected, I want to show only teams dedicated to that product.